# Account has permissions, but gets no permissions error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using the folowing script in c# to determine whether the sqlserver service account has permissions on a directory.

```
public static bool userhasaccess(string username, string path)
{
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
    bool control_allowed = false;
    bool control_denied = false;
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
    {                
        if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.ToLower() == username.ToLower())
        {
            if (rule.FileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.Read
                    || rule.FileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.FullControl
                    || rule.FileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute
                    || rule.FileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.ReadData
                    )
            {
                if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                    control_allowed = true;
                if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                    control_denied = true;
            }

        }
    }
    return (control_denied ? false : control_allowed);
}
```

This isn't perfect, because it could overlook groups, but I've stepped through the code using my specific example, and there's no deny permissions on my folder. (\\server\directory).

I then execute a SqlCommand `restore HEADERONLY from disk = N'\\server\directory\file.bak'` which should give the restore headers for a file in this directory.

This gave me the following error:

```
Cannot open backup device '\\server\directory\file.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
```

Why is this happenning when according to GetAccessRules this account has FullControl on this directory?

Comment: Check the Share permissions for that location not only the directory permissions.

Comment: Is this what you mean by that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089993/how-to-read-a-folders-sharing-permissions-from-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, you could use something like that to find out the share permissions.

Comment: I've tried using the link above, but I just keep getting the error "This shared resource does not exist". Do you have any further advice?

Comment: As the first comment in that link, I recommend taking a look at this link [NetShareGetInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsadsi/archive/2012/03/30/to-read-shared-permissions-of-a-server-resource-in-c-using-netsharegetinfo.aspx)

Comment: That's what I was using - and that's where the error came from. :-(